# C# Repository Factory

Tags: c#

I`m trying to come up with a factory static class that initiates the correct class using 2 arguments

1 - Pass the DB Table Name

2 - Pass the repository type (can be extended to used by EF, CSV, XML, Service WCF, etc...)

I wrote a simple console app (check the code bellow - is using regions for better readability) that you can use by copy/paste to a single C# console program.

I have 2 goals:

1st - In the static void Main you see that I`m using dynamic run time loading of the object to call the Methods implemented by the objects Interface. I would rather call/see the methods to display after I do varName.MethodName();. I commented out the sections that I`m trying to make it work with the name //This does not Work.

2nd - The second goal (after the first one is completed :)) is to strongly type the arguments passed to the RepositoryFactory.GetRepository(); rather than passing strings to it. In this one I tried to pass enum values but it also dodn`t work.

Thank you in advanced for your help.

```
    using System;

namespace AppTests
{
    #region Repositories

    #region Computers
    public class RepositoryComputersSQL : IRepositoryComputers
    {
        public void GetComputers()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Returning COMPUTERS SQL information...");
        }
    }

    public class RepositoryComputersXML : IRepositoryComputers
    {
        public void GetComputers()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Returning COMPUTERS XML information...");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Users
    public class RepositoryUsersSQL : IRepositoryUsers
    {
        public void GetUsers()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Returning USER SQL information...");
        }
    }

    public class RepositoryUsersXML : IRepositoryUsers
    {
        public void GetUsers()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Returning USER XML information...");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #endregion

    #region Interfaces
    public interface IRepository
    {
    }
    public interface IRepositoryComputers : IRepository
    {
        void GetComputers();
    }
    public interface IRepositoryUsers : IRepository
    {
        void GetUsers();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Repository Factory
    public static class RepositoryFactory
    {
        public static IRepository GetRepository(string repositoryTable, string repositoryType)
        {
            IRepository results = null;

            switch (repositoryTable)
            {
                case "Computers":
                    if (repositoryType == "SQL")
                    {
                        results = new RepositoryComputersSQL();
                    }
                    else if (repositoryType == "XML")
                    {
                        results = new RepositoryComputersXML();
                    }
                    else
                        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Repository Type");
                    break;

                case "Users":
                    if (repositoryType == "SQL")
                    {
                        results = new RepositoryUsersSQL();
                    }
                    else if (repositoryType == "XML")
                    {
                        results = new RepositoryUsersXML();
                    }
                    else
                        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Repository Type");
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Repository Table");
            }

            return results;
        }
    }
    #endregion


    //Exe Console
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Computers
            var repoCpSql = RepositoryFactory.GetRepository("Computers", "SQL");
            //This doesn`t work
            //repoCpSql.GetComputers();
            dynamic CpSQL = repoCpSql;
            CpSQL.GetComputers();

            IRepository repoCpxMl = RepositoryFactory.GetRepository("Computers", "XML");
            //This doesn`t work
            //repoCpxMl.GetComputers();
            dynamic CpXML = repoCpxMl;
            CpXML.GetComputers();

            // Users
            IRepository repoUsSql = RepositoryFactory.GetRepository("Users", "SQL");
            //This doesn`t work
            //repoUsSql.GetComputers();
            dynamic usSQL = repoUsSql;
            usSQL.GetUsers();

            IRepository repoUsXml = RepositoryFactory.GetRepository("Users", "XML");
            //This doesn`t work
            //repoUsXml.GetComputers();
            dynamic usXML = repoUsXml;
            usXML.GetUsers();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

NEW CODE REVIEW - LET ME KNOW WHAT YOU THINK

```
using System;

namespace AppTests
{
    #region Public Enum Repository Selectors
    public enum Init
    {
        Users_SQL,
        Users_XML,

        Computers_SQL,
        Computers_XML,
    }
    #endregion

    #region Repositories

    #region Computers
    public class RepositoryComputersSQL : IComputersRepository
    {
        public void GetComputers()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Returning COMPUTERS SQL information...");
        }
    }

    public class RepositoryComputersXML : IComputersRepository
    {
        public void GetComputers()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Returning COMPUTERS XML information...");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Users
    public class RepositoryUsersSQL : IUsersRepository
    {
        public void GetUsers()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Returning USER SQL information...");
        }
    }

    public class RepositoryUsersXML : IUsersRepository
    {
        public void GetUsers()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Returning USER XML information...");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #endregion

    #region Interfaces
    public interface IRepository
    {
    }
    public interface IComputersRepository : IRepository
    {
        void GetComputers();
    }
    public interface IUsersRepository : IRepository
    {
        void GetUsers();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Repository Factory
    public static class RepositoryFactory
    {
        private enum RepositoryTable
        {
            Users,
            Computers,
        }

        private enum RepositoryType
        {
            SQL,
            XML,
        }

        private static IRepository GetRepository(RepositoryTable repositoryTable, RepositoryType repositoryType)
        {
            IRepository results = null;

            switch (repositoryTable)
            {
                case RepositoryTable.Users:
                    if (repositoryType == RepositoryType.SQL)
                        results = new RepositoryUsersSQL();
                    else if (repositoryType == RepositoryType.XML)
                        results = new RepositoryUsersXML();
                    else
                        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Repository Type");
                    break;

                case RepositoryTable.Computers:
                    if (repositoryType == RepositoryType.SQL)
                        results = new RepositoryComputersSQL();
                    else if (repositoryType == RepositoryType.XML)
                        results = new RepositoryComputersXML();
                    else
                        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Repository Type");
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Repository Table");
            }

            return results;
        }

        #region Public Access Repositories

        public static IRepository StartRepository(Init repositoryType)
        {
            IRepository results = null;

            switch (repositoryType)
            {
                case Init.Users_SQL:
                    results = RepositoryFactory.GetRepository(RepositoryTable.Users, RepositoryType.SQL);
                    break;
                case Init.Users_XML:
                    results = RepositoryFactory.GetRepository(RepositoryTable.Users, RepositoryType.XML);
                    break;
                case Init.Computers_SQL:
                    results = RepositoryFactory.GetRepository(RepositoryTable.Computers, RepositoryType.SQL);
                    break;
                case Init.Computers_XML:
                    results = RepositoryFactory.GetRepository(RepositoryTable.Computers, RepositoryType.XML);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return results;
        }

        #endregion
    }
    #endregion


    //Exe Console
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IComputersRepository cp1 = (IComputersRepository)RepositoryFactory.StartRepository(Init.Computers_SQL);
            cp1.GetComputers();
            IComputersRepository cp2 = (IComputersRepository)RepositoryFactory.StartRepository(Init.Computers_XML);
            cp2.GetComputers();

            IUsersRepository us1 = (IUsersRepository)RepositoryFactory.StartRepository(Init.Users_SQL);
            us1.GetUsers();
            IUsersRepository us2 = (IUsersRepository)RepositoryFactory.StartRepository(Init.Users_XML);
            us1.GetUsers();


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't want to create an interface per repository. You don't want to create a "get all" method per repository. You want a generic `IRepository<T>` and a method `IEnumerable<T> Get()`.

Comment: Hi, the "GetAll" method is a simple test sample for this scenario... No sure how a IRepository<T> would help in this case, computers and users entities will have different methods assinged to them, that`s the reason why I have 3 interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

A few things I would suggest you:

1. Instead of `IRepositoryComputers` and `IRepositoryUsers` I would name them `IComputerRepository` and `IUserRepository`.
2. You should split your Factory into two methods to return the specifiy interface (which will solve your first problem):

   ```
   public enum RepositoryTypes
   {
     SQL = 0,
     XML = 1
   }

   public static class RepositoryFactory
   {
     public static IRepositoryComputers GetComputers(RepositoryTypes repositoryType)
     {
         if (repositoryType.Equals(RepositoryTypes.SQL))
           return new RepositoryComputersSQL();

         return new RepositoryComputersXML();            
     }

     public static IRepositoryUsers GetUsers(RepositoryTypes repositoryType)
     {
         if (repositoryType.Equals(RepositoryTypes.SQL))
             return new RepositoryUsersSQL();

         return new RepositoryUsersXML();
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: First let me explain  in this case, computers and users entities will have different methods assigned to them, that`s the reason why I have 3 interfaces.

Comment: Where`s what I come up with so far... Let me know your opinions from all of you :) Thank you...

Comment: One more thing, the DB will have about 50 different tables, users computers, groups, and so on... It will have 5 types of different repositories. An this is the reason why I`m trying to keep everything as generic as possible in single methods... My principal problem is that I can`t use a Generic Interface that switches to the computers, users, groups, etc.. entities that will load the appropriate Methods for that Entity class...